# How do I create npm module for local files on my PC?

Tags: javascript, json, github, node-modules

In my javascript code I am accessing .json file from the same local folder.

```
const data = require('../JS/countries.json');
```

When I published it on a GitHub I realized that no one, except for me can't run the program. The error says:

```
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: [ '/home/me/progs/testGit/technical-question/main.js' ]
```

From the internet I understood that I need to create a node module for passing this .json file.

Can anyone help me? I was reading articles on that topic, but I don't think I understood much.

Comment: When you published it on a GitHub I'm presuming github pages? If so the issue is `require` won't work in static hosting, you need to build your code to deploy onto gh pages. If you mean no one can run a git clone of your repo, then check ../JS/countries.json exists and you have pushed it up

Comment: git clone is working. How do I deploy it onto gh page?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Are you sure I don't have to create a node module for it? I saw that it is possible to create a module for your local files, but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules on how to do that